# Сохранить выделение текста при смене фокуса

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Я пишу крошечный wysiwyg редактор(редактирование происходит в div с атрибутом contenteditable) с парой функций и столкнулся с проблемой "потери" выделения текста при клике на какую-нибудь из кнопок управления.

Есть у кого-нибудь решение или идеи на этот счет?

Comment: Без примеров это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, сам разобрался. В ходе экспериментов обнаружил что выделение не теряется при клике на элементе `<button>`(по крайней мере в chrome и firefox), соответственно все кнопки редактора заменил на эти элементы.

Приведу так же функцию, которая оборачивает выделенный текст заданным html тегом. Будет полезна тем, кто так же пишет текстовый редактор.

```
function wrapSelectedText(tag){
        var range, tag;
        if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
            var selectedString = window.getSelection().toString();
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = '<' + tag + '>' + selectedString + '</' + tag + '>';
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), child;
            while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
                frag.appendChild(child);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            var selectedString = document.selection.createRange().text;
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.pasteHTML('<' + tag + '>' + selectedString + '</' + tag + '>');
        }
    }
```

Это слегка модифицированная функция из ответа к этому вопросу: [How to replace selected text with html in a contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-replace-selected-text-with-html-in-a-contenteditable-element)

Comment: А чем Вас не устроил range.surroundContents(newNode) ? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents