# Теряю выделение текста при клики на button

Tags: javascript, выделение-текста

Пытаюсь сделать обертку тегами текста в textarea, читая одновременно https://learn.javascript.ru/range-textrange-selection, но у меня фокус теряется при клике на button, а в интернете спрашивают в основном как снимать фокус при клике)

У [гражданина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457662/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0) такая же беда была, но у меня фокус все равно теряется.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(getSelection().toString());
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet laudantium eum ipsam repudiandae assumenda praesentium, aliquam ab, consectetur, voluptate adipisci odio. Commodi ad doloribus unde sit eos cum architecto quis distinctio tempora rem sequi, voluptate quaerat repellendus veniam officiis! Porro minima voluptate placeat velit, ab numquam ex voluptatem tenetur quae!</textarea>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

P.S. Только, что понял, что фокус теряется именно с textarea, если выделить обычный текст, то все нормально.

Comment: Надо в iframe запихать textarea. Там выделение пропадать не будет. Правда всё усложнится при этом неимоверно. Да вы сами можете видеть это прямо на этой странице. Если запустите пример, выделите текст и щёлкните за пределами примера, то выделение останется, только поменяет цвет на блеклый. А всё потому, что пример запускается в iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо сделать так:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea">asdasd asdfsdf asdfsdf dsafsdf</textarea>
<button onclick="getSel()">Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSel() // javascript
{
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = txtarea.value.substring(start, finish);
    console.log(sel);
}
</script>
```

Comment: О ясно, не знал о таких свойствах textarea.

Comment: Я хотел свой ответ дать, но теперь мне влом.